# Cannot import components from outside the NextJS project

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a project structure as below

```
- components
    - SharedComponent.js
- desktop
    - pages
        - page1.js
    - .next
- mobile
    - pages
        - page1.js
    - .next
```

There are 2 NextJs Projects. I am trying to share components between the two projects.
But I am getting an error when I try to use SharedComponents in one of the projects. SharedComponents is a React component written in JSX.

Below is the error

```
 error  in ./components/SharedComponent.js
[1] Module parse failed: Unexpected token (98:12)
[1] You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

Comment: Is there any syntax in your imported file which isnt supported by your webpack config (e.g. async await)?

Comment: i haven't provided a webpack config of my own. NextJs uses its default webpack config

Comment: ok. Is there any syntax in the imported file that is not present in all your other files?

Comment: There is JSX syntax